# Removing a conda environment with invalid name?

Tags: conda

Using PyCharm I've created a project with a conda interpreter. Pycharm automatically creates a conda environment for it. Short after, I realized I wanted another location for the project. Thus I removed the project folder. Then I realized I want to delete the conda environment.

So first I verify that the environment is there.

```
(base) C:\Users\Ludvig>conda env list
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\Ludvig\Anaconda3
2019 Proteinanalys       C:\Users\Ludvig\Anaconda3\envs\2019 Proteinanalys
```

Then I try to remove it.

```
(base) C:\Users\Ludvig>conda env remove --name "2019 Proteinanalys"
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

CondaValueError: Invalid environment name: '2019 Proteinanalys'
  Characters not allowed: ('/', ' ', ':')
```

Any thoughts on how to delete this environment?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try specifying the path using the `--prefix` flag instead:

```bash
conda env remove --prefix "C:\Users\Ludvig\Anaconda3\envs\2019 Proteinanalys"
```

or, similarly,

```bash
conda remove --all --prefix "C:\Users\Ludvig\Anaconda3\envs\2019 Proteinanalys"
```

The reason why this works is because the error you encounter occurs as part of [the code that attempts resolve a prefix path using the name](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/4.6.14/conda/base/context.py#L1272).  If you specify the path directly, then it doesn't have to run this resolve branch of the code.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `conda remove --all --prefix "path"` (i.e. remove should be without `--`), else it shows the following error (at least in my case):

```sh
conda: error: argument command: invalid choice: 'path'
(choose from 'clean', 'config', 'create', 'help', 'info', 'install', 'list', 'package', 'remove', 'uninstall', 'search', 'update', 'upgrade')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Anaconda Navigator, I could select and remove the environment.